# Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2019, ml.net

I try to do ML Net in asp webform. I created the model and my model into my webform. while run the program i got this error.  Unable to load DLL  CpuMathNative . Kindly answer about the dependency.

```
 using Microsoft.ML.Data; 
using Microsoft.ML; 
using System.IO;
 using DiabeticsML.Model;

namespace diabetics
 { 
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
 { 


    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mlContext = new MLContext();
       
        ITransformer model;
        using (var stream = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Fantasy-Pc\source\repos\diabetics\diabeticsML.Model\MLModel.zip", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            model = mlContext.Model.Load(stream, out _);
        }

        // Create a new model input with the user-provided data
        var input = new ModelInput
        {
            Gender = TextBox1.Text,
            Age = float.Parse(TextBox2.Text),
            Diet = TextBox3.Text,
            Height = float.Parse(TextBox4.Text),
            Weight = float.Parse(TextBox5.Text),
            Sbp = float.Parse(TextBox6.Text),
            Bdp = float.Parse(TextBox7.Text)
        };

        // Make the prediction
        var predictionEngine = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<ModelInput, ModelOutput>(model);
        var prediction = predictionEngine.Predict(input);

        // Display the prediction result
        Label8.Text = prediction.ToString();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: The error should have more details we need to see. Possible problems ranges from its just not there or has the wrong bitness (32bit vs. 64bit).

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.DllNotFoundException' in Microsoft.ML.CpuMath.dll
An exception of type 'System.DllNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.ML.CpuMath.dll but was not handled in user code
Unable to load DLL 'CpuMathNative': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)  .  MY PC is 64 bit architecture

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, under project properties > Build tab, changed **Platform Target** to **x64** and found the issue is fixed.